# occasional Gnome desktop crashes, [2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed, 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell

Running a Digital Storm server with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080, and the desktop crashes or freezes occasionally. We've run all apt updates and upgrades for 20.04.3 LTS, GNOME Shell 3.36.9 with
5.11.0-34-generic kernel.

Logs show:

```
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:45:43  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:46:53  /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2047]: (II) event20 - RH USB Gaming Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
Sep 28 13:46:53  rtkit-daemon[1231]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Sep 28 13:46:53  rtkit-daemon[1231]: Successfully made thread 18807 of process 1957 owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Sep 28 13:46:53  rtkit-daemon[1231]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Sep 28 13:47:00  dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.81' (uid=1001 pid=2175 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 28 13:47:00  systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Sep 28 13:47:00  dbus-daemon[1000]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Sep 28 13:47:00  systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1632851228.7464] agent-manager: agent[de0546a1ee00c48c,:1.81/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1001]: agent registered
Sep 28 13:47:08  dbus-daemon[1962]: [session uid=1001 pid=1962] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1001 pid=2175 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  dbus-daemon[1962]: [session uid=1001 pid=1962] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1001 pid=2175 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:47:08  dbus-daemon[1962]: [session uid=1001 pid=1962] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Sep 28 13:47:08  org.gnome.Nautilus[18843]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Sep 28 13:47:08  dbus-daemon[1962]: [session uid=1001 pid=1962] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 28 13:47:09  gnome-shell[2175]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

Probabaly unrelated I also see:

```
fwupd[19086]: ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/esys_context.c:69:Esys_Initialize() Initialize default tcti. ErrorCode (0x000a000a)
```

[This sounds](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/709) similar with the same errors but it's 21.04. And we recently disabled hibernation, or at least we think we did.

```
sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

● sleep.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit sleep.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

● hibernate.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit hibernate.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● hybrid-sleep.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit hybrid-sleep.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out these messages are a bit of a red herring. Although there still may be an issue with GDM, the real issue is that at least one of the memory modules is bad and that's what was causing the freezing. What made this even more annoying was we could not get Memtest86 to run, as a working memory chip is required on this system to even boot to a USB/DVD!